# How do I seed the random generator and create a random int in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, random

I have seen some examples of the random int in Objective-C, but all people are complaining about the same number sequence every time the application runs. I have read about seeding the random number, but I am not sure what that even means.

How can a random number be generated differently every time, even after application has relaunched?

Could some data be stored in NSUserDefaults and then, depending on that, different values get generated?

Comment: Possible duplicate of another SO article, Generating Random Numbers in Objective-C

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a [discussion on the Apple developer forums](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1590314&tstart=0).

> Use arc4random() instead of either
>   random() or rand(). It used
>   /dev/urandom and generates much better
>   pseudo-random numbers. Both rand() and
>   random() are basically bad random
>   number generators.
>
> See: man arc4random

```
#include <stdlib.h>
picknumber = arc4random() % 3 + 1;
```

Comment: how can I get a random between 1 and 10 using arc4Random()?

Comment: picknumber = arc4random() % 10 + 1;

Answer (score 5):

You can seed your random with the following code:

```
srand([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);
```

This will give you a new random sequence every time.

Comment: This doesn't change sequence from random() in iOS simulator

Answer (score 1):

I've been using `arc4random`, which you don't need to seed. You can give it a try.