# Why Rand() always generates random numbers with fixed Unique Group count?

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, random, nsarray

Even though , I execute the below code again & again I get the same Output. But , I think it should not:

```
int ObjectCount =500;
NSMutableArray *mut_arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:0];
for (int i = 0; i<ObjectCount ; i++)
{    
 [mut_arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: rand()%ObjectCount]];
}
NSSet* uniqueSet = [NSSet setWithArray:mut_arr];    
NSLog(@"Array of %d objects generates %d Unique Objects",[mut_arr count],[uniqueSet count]);
```

The output is as follows:

Array of 500 objects generates 317 Unique Objects

Here, Since the array contains random numbers the unique set count should be same again & again for same ObjectCount.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322603/how-do-i-seed-the-random-generator-and-create-a-random-int-in-objective-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not actually generating unique `NSNumber` objects; some of them are equal.

A `NSArray` can contain multiple objects that are equal. A `NSSet` can not. This is why the set created from your array has less objects.

The reason why you're always getting 317 objects is that you're using `rand()` without seeding: [Why do I always get the same sequence of random numbers with rand()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108780/why-do-i-always-get-the-same-sequence-of-random-numbers-with-rand)

Consider using `arc4random()` instead, which is seeding automatically.

Comment: Thanks.,Can you put some solid insight that why it always generates number with uniqueset value between 315 to 325 when suggested arc4random() or seed updation is used ?

Comment: @itechnician This has to do with the probability of generating duplicate values. You're basically telling the app to give you 500 random integers between 0 and 499. Some of them are bound to be duplicates. See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem

Answer (score 1):

Use like this

```
[mut_arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(arc4random() % (ObjectCount-1) + 1)]];
```

Comment: arc4random is almost always overkill, and not needed to solve this issue. Additionally: IFF, then arc4random_uniform(u_int32_t upper_bound) should be used instead of `arc4random() % (ObjectCount-1)`

Comment: Can you put some solid insight that why it always generates number with uniqueset value between 315 to 325 when suggested arc4random() or seed updation is used ?